# Shrine - How to prevent Shrine from auto uploading files prior to validation - Ruby Upload Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, shrine, antivirus-integration

This question is for anyone who has experience with the Ruby Gem Shrine for File Uploads.

I am trying to scan file uploads for viruses using ClamAV. The scan works well however the file is already auto uploaded to cloud storage by Shrine prior to validation.

- Is there a hook/callback in Shrine we can use to run the scan prior to file is uploaded?
- Is there are an alternative approach?

Here is the code at the moment.

```
Attacher.validate do
    if file
      tmp_file = file.download
      # raise Services::Clamav::Client::FileContainVirus
      errors << "virus file" if Services::Clamav::Client.virus?(tmp_file.path)
    end
 end
```

Any thoughts/answers will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, note about uploading files through Shrine. All files first get uploaded to a cache/temporary storage (usually on local filesystem), and are persisted in the final storage only after validations pass. Thus, the validations you run are ran on the cached file, and if a virus (or other validation failure) is detected, it won't be promoted to the permanent storage. You can learn more about how this works in the [Shrine Getting Started guide](https://shrinerb.com/docs/getting-started).

However, the [documentation demonstrates custom validations like this](https://shrinerb.com/docs/validation#custom-validations):

```
require "streamio-ffmpeg"

class VideoUploader < Shrine
  plugin :add_metadata

  add_metadata :duration do |io|
    movie = Shrine.with_file(io) { |file| FFMPEG::Movie.new(file.path) }
    movie.duration
  end

  Attacher.validate do
    if file.duration > 5*60*60
      errors << "duration must not be longer than 5 hours"
    end
  end
end
```

The `add_metadata` blocks are passed an `io` instance that can be used to read the file stream, or it can be promoted to a file object using `Shrine.with_file(io)`. You could achieve your goal by adding metadata `:is_virus?` and checking that upon validation. (Note that ClamAV actually supports streaming through `clamdscan --stream -`, so you can directly use the `io` instance instead of promoting to a file.)